# Equivalent of set_table_name in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

What is the equivalent of `set_table_name` in `Mongoid`? Since `mongodb` doesn't require `collection` to be created before saving `documents` into it, Is it possible to dynamically configure my `model` to save data to different `collections`.

eg: I have a `models` - `Company` and `User`.
I want to be able to save each company's users to its own users `collection`, say `company1_users, company2_users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html), you can use `store_in` to change where the document will be stored :

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: "citizens", database: "other", session: "secondary"
end
```